# Email sent to 3 colleagues addressing office gossip and was cc to HR and another senior official

Tags: communication

I received an email regarding office gossip which was cc to the head of the department. When I emailed my boss for clarification she did not respond. After some research and in person conversation with my boss days after, she said she didn’t believe it was me but she needed to address everyone in the email. I thought that was unprofessional as she should have validated the information first before sending an email implicating me as a source of the gossip.

I took offense to it. Should my boss retract the email?

Comment: Welcome on Workplace. I am not exactly sure I understand: is this a case where your boss accused you of spreading specific gossip in the office, and cc'ed the head of department while accusing you in written form via email? If that's the case, I would ask my line manager to provide a written explanation to you and everybody else this has been exposed to, as you would have been falsely accused.

Comment: Were there other colleagues who work for this boss who weren't included in the email? Sometimes this kind of thing is communicated to a group in order to avoid singling anyone out

Comment: 'before sending an email implicating me as a source of the gossip' was there anything in the email stating this?

Answer (score 3):

You just gained some valuable experience.

Never in future put anything in writing that you wouldn't be comfortable with backing up or others seeing who are not your intended recipients. You cannot control what happens to a communication after it leaves your hands.

For many people it's normal to point out the source of information to everyone concerned. Do not assume anonymity.